# MySQL: joining three tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in the database, one is equipment table:

```
eid       Name                 
 1       NY-CBC        
 2       CHI-DAD   
 3       AU-CA6 
 4       LA-AD3
```

one is Status table:

```
sid cid   high-th     Low-th  Status    Check
 3    1        90         50       0       2018-10-29 13:20:01
 3    2        80         40       0       2018-10-29 13:20:01
 4    1        90         50       0       2018-10-29 13:20:01
 4    2        80         40       0       2018-10-29 13:20:01
```

another is value table :

```
sid  cid       counts              Get
 3    1         7000             2018-10-29 13:20:01
 3    2         5000             2018-10-29 13:20:01
 4    1         12000             2018-10-29 13:20:01
 4    2         16000             2018-10-29 13:20:01
```

that the "sid"  and "cid" column in the "Status" and "value" table are all points to the "eid" column in the "equipment " table.

I need to join these tables. So the output table should be like,

```
sid   sName    cid    cName    high-th  Low-th  Status  counts   Get 
3    AU-CA6    1      NY-CBC    90        50       0   70000    2018-10-29 13:20:01  
3    AU-CA6    2      CHI-DAD   80        40       0    5000    2018-10-29 13:20:01
4    LA-AD3    1     NY-CBC     90        50       0    12000   2018-10-29 13:20:01
4    LA-AD3    2      CHI-DAD   80        40       0    16000   2018-10-29 13:20:01
```

Any help much be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Tip: NEVER include a minus character ('-') in a table/column identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inner join using multiple instance of equipment table

```
select 
   s.sid,e.name as sName,
   s.cid,e1.name as cName,
   s.high-th,s.Low-th,s.Status,
   v.counts,v.Get 
from status s inner join value v on s.sid=v.sid and s.cid=v.cid
inner join equipment e on s.sid=e.eid
inner join equipment e1 on s.cid=e1.eid
```

Comment: @fe06, a table ??

Comment: @georgetovrea, no that was a mistake. I've modified the answer - you can check now